# File Encoding error while sending file via TCP with VB.Net and receiving with Socket in Python3.6

Tags: python-3.x, vb.net, tcp, file-transfer

I have a zip file in VB.Net created with `ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory("temp/", "payload.zip", CompressionLevel.Optimal, True)` that I send to my python server with :

```vb
Dim payload() As Byte = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(System.Convert.ToBase64String(System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes("payload.zip")))
Dim payloadstr As String = byteArrToString(payload)
Dim client As New TcpClient("192.168.0.160", 42069)
Dim PayloadWriter As New StreamWriter(client.GetStream())

PayloadWriter.Write(payloadstr)
PayloadWriter.Flush()
PayloadWriter.Close()
client.Close()
```

The `byteArrToString()` function looks like :

```vb
Public Function byteArrToString(ByVal arr() As Byte) As String

    Return System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetString(arr)

End Function
```

on python server side, My code looks like:

```
import socket               # Import socket module
import random,string,io

def randomString(stringLength=10):
 letters = string.ascii_lowercase
 return ''.join(random.choice(letters) for i in range(stringLength))

s = socket.socket()         # Create a socket object
host = "192.168.0.160"      # Define Hostname
port = 42069                # Reserve a port for your service.
s.bind((host, port))        # Bind to the port
s.listen(5)                 # Now wait for client connection.
irName = randomString(10) + ".zip"
ir = io.open(irName,"wb")
print ("Listening now")
while True:
    c, addr = s.accept()    # Establish connection with client.
    print ('Got connection from', addr)
    print ("Receiving Data...")
    print ("Writing as " + irName)
    l = c.recv(4096)
    while (l):
        ir.write(l)
        l = c.recv(4096)
    ir.close()
    c.close()
    print ("Done receiving")
```

Somehow the Payload.zip I receive on server side has double the size of Payload.zip in Windows and the System refuses to recognize it as a valid ZIP file. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### The explanation

You are messing around a lot with string encoding on the VB.NET side, which you really shouldn't and also don't need to do in this case. To help you get an understanding of what's going on, here's an overview of what your code does right now:

**VB.NET**

1. Reads the compressed file into memory as an array of bytes.
2. Converts the byte array into a Base64-encoded string.
3. Converts the Base64 string directly into an array of bytes (note: this is different from the array in step 1).
4. Converts that byte array *back* into a string again, but this time using UTF-16/Unicode encoding.
5. Sends it to the Python side using a `StreamWriter`, which may or may not add a BOM to the beginning of the stream.

**Python**

1. Receives the data sent from VB.NET.
2. Writes it to a file.

In Python you haven't done anything to reverse the steps you took in the VB.NET code, so that's why the data is different.

As of step 3 you are also working with a completely different byte array which no longer represents the *raw* data of the compressed file, but rather the Base64-encoded version of it. Generally speaking, Base64 usually increases the size of data by about 1.5x, so that's why you're seeing an increase in size.

Strictly speaking, what you *would* need to do on the Python side to reverse the process in this case is:

1. Take the all the received data (which in Python is a string).
2. Decode it from Base64.
3. Write to file.

The switcharoo between encodings (UTF-8 to 16/Unicode in step 4) shouldn't do much in terms of the data itself as it mostly affects how the string is displayed, so this isn't really something you need to reverse.

### The answer

I'm guessing the reason you're doing all the string-related work on the VB.NET side is because Python sockets handles its data as strings. But you should know that in the background (even in Python) a string is and always will be an array of bytes, no matter what.

I understand the confusion and I've seen it many times before, but encoding is mostly just a way of storing and/or displaying text. The only way you are going to lose data is if you are trying to display it using an incompatible encoding. But in this case you're not working with text, you're working with *raw data*. Therefore, as long as you are not trying to display it or manipulate it *through* a string, there's no need to convert it at all.

All you (should) need to do is to take the byte array returned from `File.ReadAllBytes()` and send it directly to Python.

```vb
Dim payload() As Byte = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes("payload.zip")

Using client As New TcpClient("192.168.0.160", 42069)
    Using stream As NetworkStream = client.GetStream()
        stream.Write(payload)
    End Using
End Using
```

The `Using`/`End Using` blocks take care of closing and disposing the objects for you.